# undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm running a Rails 2.3.5 application and upon running script/server I am shown the following:

```
./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path': undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:60:in `load_initializer'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:44:in `run'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:17:in `boot!'
    from ./script/../config/boot.rb:123
    from script/server:2:in `require'
    from script/server:2
```

If I comment out line 60 in boot.rb (Rails::GemDependency.add_frozen_gem_path) and run script/server, I get this:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path': undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:298:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/developer/bigpink/config/environment.rb:13
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/developer/bigpink/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from script/server:3:in `require'
    from script/server:3
```

So, not really sure what to do. Hoping I can get some quick help. Thanks!

Answer (score 299, accepted):

I just ran into this problem myself while trying to upgrade an older Rails app from REE 1.8.7 to 1.9.3-p385. Oddly, Ruby 1.9.3-p327 works just fine. What it came down to was ruby-1.9.3-p385 had installed RubyGems version 2.0.2 for me, and 1.9.3-p327 has RubyGems v1.8.23 installed.

`Gem.source_index` has been deprecated for a while, but since Rails 2.3 is not getting any updates except critical security patches, this will never get fixed. RubyGems v2.0 finally removed that method. Downgrade to any `rubygems` version prior to 2.0.0, like 1.8.25 to get the functionality back for now. You can get a compatible version using `gem update --system 1.8.25`.

As a very important aside, Rails 2.3.5 needs to be updated to a minimum of 2.3.17. There are critical security vulnerabilities that open you up to some very nasty attacks. In the long term, upgrading to 3.x needs to be considered a very strong need.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly. And yes, thanks, I am in the midst of upgrading to 2.3.17, and then to the latest 3.x.

Comment: @uxp Any tips for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374188/why-is-my-rake-call-causing-an-undefined-method-source-index-error/15378764

Comment: Thank you. I also ran into this problem upgrading from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3-p385

Comment: Thank you so much. I ran into the same problem with our Redmine installation.

Comment: Anyone using [RVM](http://rvm.io/) can call `rvm rubygems latest-1.8` to downgrade rubygems and fix this issue.

Comment: Martin's comment (Anyone using RVM can call rvm rubygems latest-1.8 to downgrade rubygems and fix this issue. ) helped me resolve my issue, where I was stuck since few hours. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Need to force downgrading rubygems: `rvm rubygems --force latest-1.8`

Comment: damn, downgrading rubygems for rvm, that's inconvenient, is't it.. guess that Rails 2 is just as good as dead.

Answer (score 32):

for rvm users,

```
rvm install rubygems 1.8.2 --force
```

Comment: I had to go back to 1.6.2 to make this work. But it was this command that was needed.

Answer (score 26):

This helped me: http://djellemah.com/blog/2013/02/27/rails-23-with-ruby-20/

I did this in combination with `gem update --system 1.8.25`, which might not be needed for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to install slimgems: `gem install slimgems`.  This is a drop-in fork of RubyGems that works better with old versions.

Answer (score 0):

Update: In addition to the @uxp answer, if you running this command on a Mac running Catalina, there is a small change in command, you need to add -n.

So the command would be `sudo gem update --system -n 1.8.25`