# `add_frozen_gem_path': undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError) i am getting this error when i try running my server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

```
from /home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:298:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /home/rakesh/rails/rankfedena/config/environment.rb:6
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:112:in `require'
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `gem_original_require'
    from /home/rakesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:64:in `require'
    from ./script/server:3
```

Comment: I tried updating my rubygems as well to gem update --system 1.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably could format your question better in order to receive more replies. It is a little vague/hard to understand based on what you have written.

Try this out and see if it helps you in any way. [undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349869/undefined-method-source-index-for-gemmodule-nomethoderror)

Answer (score 7):

Update you gem to 1.8.25

```
gem update --system 1.8.25
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349869/undefined-method-source-index-for-gemmodule-nomethoderror) may help you lot.