# error rake generate_session_store installing redmine-1.1.1

Tags: ruby, centos, redmine

My company need to upgrade their current Redmine1.1.1 server. In order to avoid productions issue, I am trying to recreate a working instance with identical version. That's why I can't use standard solution which mainly modify the gems or rail version.

I need to create an instance of a redmine-1.1.1 CentOS6 server with the following rubygems version:

```
[root@localhost redmine1]# rpm -qa |grep ruby
rubygem-rack-1.1.0-2.el6.noarch
rubygem-daemon_controller-1.1.5-1.el6.noarch
rubygems-1.3.7-5.el6.noarch ruby-ri-1.8.7.374-4.el6_6.i686
ruby-1.8.7.374-4.el6_6.i686 rubygem-rake-0.8.7-2.1.el6.noarch
ruby-mysql-2.8.2-1.el6.i686 ruby-irb-1.8.7.374-4.el6_6.i686
rubygems-devel-1.3.7-5.el6.noarch ruby-devel-1.8.7.374-4.el6_6.i686
rubygem-passenger-3.0.21-11.el6.i686
rubygem-passenger-native-libs-3.0.21-11.el6.i686
ruby-rdoc-1.8.7.374-4.el6_6.i686 ruby-docs-1.8.7.374-4.el6_6.i686
rubygem-passenger-native-3.0.21-11.el6.i686
ruby-libs-1.8.7.374-4.el6_6.i686 rubygem-fastthread-1.0.7-2.2.i686
```

I followed the tutorials below in order to recreate the redmine install.

https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Redmine+Apache+Passenger_InstallOnRedHat

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_Redmine_on_CentOS_5

I got this error and knowing that I can't downgrade my gems, what are the other options to overcome this?

```
[root@localhost redmine1]# rake generate_session_store 

rake aborted!
undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module
/var/www/redmine1/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in
`add_frozen_gem_path' /var/www/redmine1/config/boot.rb:47:in
`load_initializer' /var/www/redmine1/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
/var/www/redmine1/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
/var/www/redmine1/config/boot.rb:122 /var/www/redmine1/Rakefile:4
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@redmine111/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What are the necessary complements to help you understand this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined method \`source\_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349869/undefined-method-source-index-for-gemmodule-nomethoderror)

Comment: Why are you installing Redmine 1.1.1? That version is five years old, and not even the latest release in either the 1.x nor 1.1.x series...

Comment: My company need to upgrade their current Redmine1.1.1 server. In order to avoid productions issue, i am trying to recreate a working instance with identical version. That's why i can't use standard solution which mainly modify the gems or rail version.