# Rails server 503 Service Unavailable Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, passenger

when I start my rails server using `ruby script/server` command, I am getting the following response

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.9 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@gemset1/gems/rails-2.3.9/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path': undefined method `source_index' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@gemset1/gems/rails-2.3.9/lib/initializer.rb:298:in `add_gem_load_paths'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@gemset1/gems/rails-2.3.9/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@gemset1/gems/rails-2.3.9/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@gemset1/gems/rails-2.3.9/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
        from /home/ubuntu/apps/moogle/config/environment.rb:13
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@gemset1/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@gemset1/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@gemset1/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@gemset1/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@gemset1/gems/rails-2.3.9/lib/commands/server.rb:84
        from script/server:3:in `require'
        from script/server:3
```

I am using ProxyPreseve like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

And I am getting 503 Service Unavailable Error. Can anyone tell me whats wrong in my application?

Rails version: 2.3.9
Ruby version: 1.8.7-p374
Bundle version: 1.12.5
Gem version: 2.0.17

Comment: Just to confirm: Are you really trying to run Rails `2.3.9` on Ruby `1.8.7`?

Comment: @spickermann - Yes, that's right.

Comment: something wrong with `rubygems` version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349869/undefined-method-source-index-for-gemmodule-nomethoderror

Comment: Both version are outdated and unmaintained for more than 3 years. Rails 2.3 has known security issues that will not be fixed anymore. Furthermore current gems will not run with Ruby 1.8.7 anymore. I suggest to start updating your application to current versions of Rails and Ruby with a high priority.

Comment: @spickermann - I know but I need to first run the application so that I can upgrade it. I can't directly run the application with latest version or Ruby. I first have to get it running in 1.8.7 and then I can try to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to downgrade the `rubygems` version

```
gem update --system 1.8.25
```

refer solution to the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15351437/4758119)